# Slick slider not working within jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have a carousel working with slick slider working fine in first tab, but when I go to second tab, the slider is not loading, if I open the second tab by default then not loading in second tab but not first tab by then, I think slick slider code is initialized  and then its not again initializing when tab is changed, but not sure how to handle this, can somebody please suggest?

Here is the working [JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/ssgq6sxo/)

The jQuery for the tab is following:

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
});
if (window.location.hash.length > 0) {
  var hash_str= window.location.hash.split("#")[1];
  $('.tab-link[data-tab=' + hash_str + ']').click();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know the webpage looks good as it is, but could you strip away everything in your code that isn't absolutely necessary to your issue? Also, `if I open the second tab by default then not loading in second tab but not first tab`. Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: @JavaSpyder I have two sliders working in both of the tabs, the problem is, slider/carousel not working in next tab.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason behind this is, slick refuses to initialize properly on inactive tabs - for they (inactive tabs) consist of a `display:none` css property. Therefore try setting hidden tabs' css as follow:

```
{
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And then you also need to reset the `height` property back to its size when a hidden tab becomes active. For this you would just do the following:

```
{
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of making div invisible.

Comment: I'm not sure about the accessibility of this solution since having invisible divs can be confusing for screen readers. Can anyone speak to this?

Answer (score 9):

You can also refresh the slicks on tab's click function as follows:

```
$('.best-selling-slide2').slick('refresh');
$('.best-selling-slide').slick('refresh');
```

It worked for me...!

Comment: Thank you! It's weird that Slick doesn't mention this on their list of Methods. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: yeah this method is the best way, just add it to your click action and you are all set.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working finally with resize method:

Just had to add the `resize()` for both the sliders.

```
$('.best-selling-slide2').resize();
$('.best-selling-slide').resize();
```

Adding this in tab click function would help!

Here is my working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/ssgq6sxo/13/)

Just posting this as answer because if anybody face this kind of issue in future and come to this page

Another fix I have found is within CSS, the tab CSS is being changed from `display:none` to `display:block`, because the width of slider doesn't get applied when element is hidden, to fix this, I have modified the CSS to following:

```
.tab-content {/*display: none;*/ position:absolute; left:-9999px;}
.tab-content.current {/*display: inherit;*/ position:relative; left:0;}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried `resize()` and it was working only for the first tab. I used `$('.your-element').slick('setPosition');` and it was working.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I would like to add that the function should be applied to the *slider* element, not to the *slides*: `$(this).find('.slider').slick('setPosition');`

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `slicksetoptions` in jquery on tab click:

```
$('.your-element').slick("slickSetOption", "draggable", true, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane{ display: block; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; }
.tab-content>.active{ height: auto;}
```